# How to prevent portrait mode orientation in windows Store app(Tablet)?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have develop windows tab version , I tried to set landscape .

I go to edit Package.appxmanifest

```
        <m2:InitialRotationPreference>
          <m2:Rotation Preference="landscape" />
          <m2:Rotation Preference="landscapeFlipped" />
        </m2:InitialRotationPreference>
```

Any other solution for  landscape  mode orientation set default .

Answer (score 2):

If you remove portrait mode from the app manifest (I suggest using the manifest designer instead of the a text editor), then you can disable portrait mode completely.

[image]

Comment: Hi Nate Diamond, Thanks for sharing. I have selected only landscape. And then I tried to run simulator but rotate portrait and landscape.  How to prevent portrait mode in simulator (i haven't device).

Comment: That should prevent it in itself. The only other thing that could be happening is if you're actively listening for orientation changes and responding to them in your app. Make sure you're not using LayoutAwarePage anywhere and that you're not processing any changes such as in ViewChange or SizeChange events.